# Why do we prefer to add 'assign' attribute to C primitive properties? (bool, NSInteger, CGFloat ect)

Tags: objective-c, xcode

Why do we prefer to add 'assign' attribute to C primitive properties? (bool, NSInteger, CGFloat ect)

Would the world end otherwise?

Comment: `assign` is the default, but adding it does make the intent clear.  There is no related attributed that would make sense, and in fact, the compiler won't let you use one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No the world would not end, as it's the default attribute for primitive types anyway.

I guess we do it to be more explicit about the memory management being applied to the property, in the same way we use keywords that are the default anyway (for example `unsigned int`).

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering. For detail, what's the difference does 'assign' make to OC float compared to C float?

Comment: It makes no difference; they are the same thing.